# LSM303 + ESP-IDF: Accelerometer works but magnetometer gives the same reading unless power cycled

Tags: esp32, magnetometer, esp-idf

I am using an [LSM303](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm303dlhc.pdf) sensor, connected via I2C to an ESP32 and programmed via ESP-IDF to retrieve the magnetometer and accelerometer data. I was previously using an Ardunio and the the Pololu LSM303 library and everything worked with the same wiring.

However, when using ESP-IDF, it seems like I have messed something up as the magnetometer data freezes unless I power cycle the LSM303 (rebooting the ESP32 doesn't seem to change the readings).

Here is the code, which reads the data at 50 Hz via I2C. I have checked various sources including this forum and others but I am worried I missed something that may actually be quite obvious.

```
#include "lsm303v2_[obscuredfilename].h"
#include "driver/i2c.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"

#define LSM303_ADDR_ACCEL 0x19 // Accelerometer I2C address //0x19 seems to work 
#define LSM303_ADDR_MAG   0x1E // Magnetometer I2C address

// Register addresses
#define LSM303_CTRL_REG1_A 0x20
#define LSM303_CTRL_REG4_A 0x23
#define LSM303_OUT_X_L_A   0x28
#define LSM303_CTRL_REG1_M 0x20
#define LSM303_CTRL_REG2_M 0x21
#define LSM303_CTRL_REG3_M 0x22
#define LSM303_CTRL_REG4_M 0x23
#define LSM303_OUT_X_H_M   0x03

//self added test
#define LSM303_OUT_X_L_M   0x04

//self added for setting to cont mode
#define LSM303_SR_REG_M 0x09
#define LSM303_MR_REG_M 0x02

// Circular buffer settings
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100 // 50 Hz * 2 seconds = 100 samples
#define BUFFER_MASK (BUFFER_SIZE - 1)

static lsm303_data_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
static volatile uint32_t buffer_head = 0;

//static esp_err_t i2c_init(void);
//static esp_err_t lsm303_read_bytes(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *data, uint8_t len);

// new code
static esp_err_t i2c_init(void)
{
    i2c_config_t conf = {
        .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER,
        .sda_io_num = GPIO_NUM_21,
        .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .scl_io_num = GPIO_NUM_22,
        .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .master.clk_speed = 400000
    };

    i2c_param_config(I2C_NUM_0, &conf);
    return i2c_driver_install(I2C_NUM_0, conf.mode, 0, 0, 0);
}

static esp_err_t lsm303_read_bytes(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *data, uint8_t len)
{
    if (len == 0) {
        return ESP_OK;
    }

    i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (addr << 1) | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, reg, true);
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (addr << 1) | I2C_MASTER_READ, true);

    if (len > 1) {
        i2c_master_read(cmd, data, len - 1, I2C_MASTER_ACK);
    }

    i2c_master_read_byte(cmd, data + len - 1, I2C_MASTER_NACK);
    i2c_master_stop(cmd);

    esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_NUM_0, cmd, pdMS_TO_TICKS(10)); //was 1000ms
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

    return ret;
}

static esp_err_t lsm303_write_bytes(uint8_t addr, const uint8_t *data, uint8_t len)
{
    if (len == 0) {
        return ESP_OK;
    }

    i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (addr << 1) | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true);
    i2c_master_write(cmd, data, len, true);
    i2c_master_stop(cmd);

    esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_NUM_0, cmd, pdMS_TO_TICKS(10));
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

    return ret;
}
//end of new code

void lsm303_init()
{
    i2c_init();

    // Set up the accelerometer
    uint8_t accel_config[2] = {LSM303_CTRL_REG1_A, 0x47}; // 50 Hz, normal mode, all axes enabled
    lsm303_write_bytes(LSM303_ADDR_ACCEL, accel_config, 2);

    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100)); //self added for debugging
    // Set up the magnetometer
    //uint8_t mag_config[5] = {LSM303_CTRL_REG1_M, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; // 50 Hz, low power mode, continuous conversion
    uint8_t mag_config[5] = {LSM303_CTRL_REG1_M, 0x1C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; // 50 Hz, high power mode, continuous conversion
    lsm303_write_bytes(LSM303_ADDR_MAG, mag_config, 5);
    

    //doesn't seem to fix the problem either
    //lsm303_write_bytes(LSM303_ADDR_MAG, LSM303_MR_REG_M, 0x00);
    uint8_t data[2] = {LSM303_MR_REG_M, 0x00};
    lsm303_write_bytes(LSM303_ADDR_MAG, data , 1);
}

void sensor_read_task(void *arg)
{
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();

    while (1)
    {
        lsm303_data_t data;

        // Read magnetometer data //note: originally it was accel data first but I decided to swap it around to see if it fixes the problem 
        uint8_t mag_data[6];
        lsm303_read_bytes(LSM303_ADDR_MAG, LSM303_OUT_X_H_M, mag_data, 6); //was X_H_M
        data.mx = (int16_t)(mag_data[0] << 8 | mag_data[1]);
        data.my = (int16_t)(mag_data[2] << 8 | mag_data[3]);
        data.mz = (int16_t)(mag_data[4] << 8 | mag_data[5]);
        /*lsm303_read_bytes(LSM303_ADDR_MAG, LSM303_OUT_X_L_M, mag_data, 6); //was X_H_M
        data.mx = (int16_t)(mag_data[1] << 8 | mag_data[0]);
        data.my = (int16_t)(mag_data[3] << 8 | mag_data[2]);
        data.mz = (int16_t)(mag_data[5] << 8 | mag_data[4]);*/

        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(10));

        // Read accelerometer data
        uint8_t accel_data[6];
        lsm303_read_bytes(LSM303_ADDR_ACCEL, LSM303_OUT_X_L_A | 0x80, accel_data, 6);
        data.ax = (int16_t)(accel_data[1] << 8 | accel_data[0]);
        data.ay = (int16_t)(accel_data[3] << 8 | accel_data[2]);
        data.az = (int16_t)(accel_data[5] << 8 | accel_data[4]);

        
        

        // Save the data to the circular buffer
        buffer[buffer_head & BUFFER_MASK] = data;
        buffer_head++;
        ESP_LOGI("lsm303v2 - sensor_read_task", "accel data %s mag data %s", accel_data, mag_data);
        ESP_LOGI("lsm303v2 - sensor_read_task", "Accel Data %hd, %hd, %hd Mag data %hd, %hd, %hd", data.ax, data.ay, data.az, data.mx, data.my, data.mz);
        // Sleep for 20 ms (50 Hz)
        vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime, pdMS_TO_TICKS(20));

        //for testing purposes, reducing to 7Hz
        //vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime, pdMS_TO_TICKS(143));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set data rate ODR[0:3] as necessary for 50 Hz read?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't think I did, so I added some code and through an i2c dump, I was able to confirm ODR (I assume it is chip 0x1E register 0x00) has hex 0x70, which is equivalent to 0b01110000. However, the freezing still occurs. Much appreciated if any guidance can be provided. Many thanks!

Comment: The value 0x70 is for 400 Hz, you may try also 0x40 for  50 Hz.

Comment: May be there is additional information for you https://www.waveshare.com/lsm303dlhc-board.htm https://www.waveshare.com/lsm303dlhc-board.htm https://learn.adafruit.com/lsm303-accelerometer-slash-compass-breakout/calibration https://www.pololu.com/product/1268 https://www.instructables.com/LSM303DLHC-exploration/ https://www.instructables.com/LSM303DLHC-exploration/ https://learn.adafruit.com/lsm303-accelerometer-slash-compass-breakout/coding

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Unfortunately it still freezes with 0x40. Just want to check that there should be no harm with choosing a higher refresh rate than the one I need? I must have messed some other config up :(. Here is a full i2c dump

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/12n4gnp/lsm303_espidf_accelerometer_works_but/

Comment: Full i2c dump https://preview.redd.it/svgpqkfv42ua1.png?width=1046&format=png&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=da3780f8400e1021aaafb9e213f9de7eccb78f0d

Comment: PS: I also had a look at the links - I was trying to reverse engineer the Poulu library as well and will continue to have a look. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!
Thanks for all the advice and guidance @Uwe

Needed to change:
Chip: 0x1E
Address: 0x02
Data: 0x0

I ended up going through the data sheet and checking the i2c dump 1 by 1 and found out!

The reason for this is in P.38 of the data sheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm303dlhc.pdf

MR_REG_M(02h) needs to be set to 0,0 to be in continuous conversion mode (the i2cdump revealed it was 0x03, which is 0b11.... in binary, representing sleep mode), but we want 0b00.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It takes a lot of time to read all the pages from 22 to 39 with the register description very carefully, but it is really worth it.